# javascript to create a search box for a list

Tags: javascript, html

I have this leaderboard:

[image: Leaderboard]

I have included a search box, where the user can search for an employee from the list.

I am using the below PHP to echo the list in the leaderboard:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="weeklylb" class="leadboardcontent">

    <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

      <ol id="myOL">
        <li>
          <mark>
            <?php while( $toprow4=s qlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt4) ) {
                      echo "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow4[ 'rank'] .
                           "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow4[ 'EmployeeName'] .
                           "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow4[ 'pointsRewarded'] .
                           "</span></div>"; } ?>
          </mark>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

Below is the code for the search box:

```
<div id="search5back">

    <form method="get" action="/search" id="searchbox5">
        <input id="search52" name="q" type="text" size="40" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search an Employee...." />
    </form>
</div>
```

The JavaScript I have tried to make the search box work:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search52");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
    li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

The JavaScript looks perfect.

Please anyone, help me rectify the mistake.

Comment: And the issue is...?

Comment: What goes  wrong? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: @Siyual I am not able to search for a person from the list using the above codes.I dont know where exactly I'm making the mistake.

Comment: No errors, in particular, but m not getting the name I am searching for in the list,when I use the search box. @Pointy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a single `li` element in `ol`. If your **DOM** stays the same, maybe this will help.

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search52");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
    li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
    divs=li[0].getElementsByClassName("parent-div");
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        a = divs[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            divs[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It works perfect.Please ,if you don't mind,kindly explain where was the mistake.it will help me improve.God bless ya.

Comment: one more thing ,the search box doesnot work when I toggle the leaderboards.It works for weekly leaderboard list.But when I toggle to the overallLeaderboard,it doesnot work.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like your `<ol>` only has one `<li>` in it. All of your "name" elements are in that one `<li>`, so you only ever check the first one here:

```
    a = li[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
```

If you search for the first name it might work.

Comment: thanks for the input.I tried that ,but its not working.The list remains the same,it doesnot get reduced to just the one name I am searching for.

Comment: Well the only thing I can suggest is to debug it. Add `console.log()` calls to verify the elements being found etc.

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Comment: one more thing ,the search box doesnot work when I toggle the leaderboards.It works for weekly leaderboard list.But when I toggle to the overallLeaderboard,it doesnot work.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your php:

```
<ol id="myOL">
    <?php while( $toprow4=s qlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt4) ) { ?>
    <li>
        <mark>
            <div class='parent-div'>
                <span class='rank'><?php echo $toprow4[ 'rank']; ?></span>
                <span class='name'><?php echo $toprow4[ 'EmployeeName']; ?></span>
                <span class='points'><?php echo $toprow4[ 'pointsRewarded']; ?></span>
            </div>
        </mark>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.But there are flaws in this php.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bad formatting : 
here is the running code. just replace your db value

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="weeklylb" class="leadboardcontent">

    <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

      <ol id="myOL">
        <li>
          <mark>
           <div class='parent-div'>
           <span class='rank'>1</span><span class='name'>test1</span><span class='points'>5</span>
           </div></mark></li>
           <li> <div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>2</span><span class='name'>test2</span><span class='points'>25</span></div></mark></li>
           <li> <div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>3</span><span class='name'>test3</span><span class='points'>35</span></div></mark></li>
           <li> <div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>4</span><span class='name'>test4</span><span class='points'>45</span>
           </div>
          </mark>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="search5back">

        <form method="get" action="/search" id="searchbox5">
        <input id="search52" name="q" type="text" size="40" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search an Employee...." />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() { 
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search52");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ol = document.getElementById("myOL");
    li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
        console.log(i);
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Comment: one more thing ,the search box doesnot work when I toggle the leaderboards.It works for weekly leaderboard list.But when I toggle to the overallLeaderboard,it doesnot work.